# Pegar valor SRC de tag Source com JS

Tags: javascript

Tenho que pegar o valor SRC da tag Source desse codigo:

```html
<video id="vp1_html5_FC" preload="auto" width="100%" height="100%" controls=""><source src="http://www.blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=23bfbcf30d33ff96" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Tentei com o seguinte script:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("vp1_html5_FC");
var tag= el.document.getElementByTagName("source")[0].src;
alert(tag);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisa de tudo isso, caso tenha somente um vídeo na página:

```js
var tag= document.querySelector("video source").src;
alert(tag);
```

```html
<video id="vp1_html5_FC" preload="auto" width="100%" height="100%" controls=""><source src="http://urldeexemplo.com/video=1" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Caso tenha mais que um vídeo na página

```js
let tags = document.querySelectorAll("video source");
tags.forEach(function(item) {
  alert(item.src);
});
```

```html
<video id="vp1_html5_FC" preload="auto" width="100%" height="100%" controls=""><source src="http://urldeexemplo.com/video=1" type="video/mp4"></video>
<video id="vp1_html5_FC" preload="auto" width="100%" height="100%" controls=""><source src="http://urldeexemplo.com/video=2" type="video/mp4"></video>
<video id="vp1_html5_FC" preload="auto" width="100%" height="100%" controls=""><source src="http://urldeexemplo.com/video=3" type="video/mp4"></video>
<video id="vp1_html5_FC" preload="auto" width="100%" height="100%" controls=""><source src="http://urldeexemplo.com/video=4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

### Referência

- [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: i love you kkk... Funcionou perfeitamente. Arigator

Comment: Só tem uma tag `source` na página ?

Comment: Sim... é uma pagina simples de video em html5, porém eu to pegando todos os links de volta para trocar de player usando um webapp...